# Branch.io with Xamarin Forms: InitSessionComplete not being called on Android app when push notification is acknowledged

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-notificationhub, branch.io

I'm using Branch.io in a Xamarin Forms app, and my goal is to send push notifications through Azure Notification Hubs with Branch links in them to open the app and do something. I seem to have it all configured perfectly fine for iOS, but in Android I'm receiving the push notification and the correct activity is coming up, but InitSessionComplete is not called on my IBranchBUOSessionInterface object.

I'm suspecting the issue is in the way I'm creating the PendingIntent, but I could be totally wrong. Again, InitSessionComplete is called in every other circumstance except for when I receive a push notification with a Branch link.

All relevant code is below. Thanks!

MainApplication.cs

```cs
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using BranchXamarinSDK;
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;

namespace MyCompany.MyApp.Droid
{
    //You can specify additional application information in this attribute
    [Application]
    [MetaData("io.branch.sdk.auto_link_disable", Value = "false")]
    [MetaData("io.branch.sdk.TestMode", Value = "true")]
    [MetaData("io.branch.sdk.BranchKey", Value = "@string/branch_key")]
    public class MainApplication : Application, Application.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks
    {
        public MainApplication (IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer)
          : base (handle, transer)
        {
        }

        public override void OnCreate ()
        {
            base.OnCreate ();
            RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks (this);
            BranchAndroid.GetAutoInstance(ApplicationContext);
        }

        public override void OnTerminate ()
        {
            base.OnTerminate ();
            UnregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks (this);
        }

        public void OnActivityCreated (Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
        }

        public void OnActivityDestroyed (Activity activity)
        {
        }

        public void OnActivityPaused (Activity activity)
        {
        }

        public void OnActivityResumed (Activity activity)
        {
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
        }

        public void OnActivitySaveInstanceState (Activity activity, Bundle outState)
        {
        }

        public void OnActivityStarted (Activity activity)
        {
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
        }

        public void OnActivityStopped (Activity activity)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.cs

```cs
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Util;
using BranchXamarinSDK;
using MyCompany.Shared.Droid.Modules;
using App = MyCompany.MyApp.Core.App;

namespace MyCompany.MyApp.Droid
{
    [Activity (Theme = "@style/Custom.Holo", 
               Label = "MyApp", 
               Icon = "@drawable/icon", 
               ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
               ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, 
               LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask, 
               MainLauncher = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "android.intent.action.VIEW" },
        Categories = new[] { "android.intent.category.DEFAULT", "android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" },
        DataScheme = "myapp",
        DataHost = "open")]

    [IntentFilter(new[] { "android.intent.action.VIEW" },
        Categories = new[] { "android.intent.category.DEFAULT", "android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" },
        DataScheme = "https",
        DataHost = "mycompanymyapp.test-app.link")]
    public class MainActivity : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity, IBranchBUOSessionInterface
    {
        public const string Tag = "MainActivity";
        private App _app;

        internal static readonly string ChannelId = "MyCompany";
        internal static readonly int NotificationId = 100;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

            if (Intent.Extras != null)
            {
                foreach (var key in Intent.Extras.KeySet())
                {
                    if (key == null) { continue; }

                    var value = Intent.Extras.GetString(key);
                    Log.Debug(Tag, "Key: {0} Value: {1}", key, value);
                }
            }

            // Removes icon from android navbar
            ActionBar.SetIcon(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);

            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, savedInstanceState);

            BranchAndroid.Debug = true;

            var androidModule = new MyCompanyAndroidServicesModule ();
            var app = new App (androidModule);

            BranchAndroid.Init(this, GetString(Resource.String.branch_key), this);
            LoadApplication(app);

            _app = app;
        }

        #region IBranchSessionInterface implementation

        public void InitSessionComplete(BranchUniversalObject buo, BranchLinkProperties blp)
        {
            _app.InitSessionComplete(buo, blp);
        }

        public void SessionRequestError(BranchError error)
        {
            _app.SessionRequestError(error);
        }

        #endregion

        protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            Intent = intent;
        }
    }
}
```

MyCompany.MyApp.Core.cs

```cs
#region Libraries
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Autofac;
using BranchXamarinSDK;
using MyCompany.Core;
using MyCompany.Core.Factories;
using MyCompany.Core.Helpers;
using MyCompany.Core.Services;
using MyCompany.Core.ViewModels;
using MyCompany.MyApp.Core.ViewModels;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Device = Xamarin.Forms.Device;

#endregion Libraries

namespace MyCompany.MyApp.Core
{
    public class App : Application, ILoginApp, IBranchBUOSessionInterface
    {
        #region Variables
        readonly IViewFactory _viewFactory;
        readonly INavigationService _navService;
        #endregion Variables

        #region Constructor
        public App (Module platformServiceModule = null)
        {
            var bootstrapper = new TimeAppBootstrapper ();

            if (platformServiceModule != null)
                bootstrapper.AddModule (platformServiceModule);

            bootstrapper.Run ();

            _viewFactory = bootstrapper.Container.Resolve<IViewFactory> ();
            _navService = bootstrapper.Container.Resolve<INavigationService> ();
            Page startView = new NavigationPage (_viewFactory.Resolve<LoginV2ViewModel> ()) {
                    BarBackgroundColor = Color.White,
                    BarTextColor = Color.FromRgb(34, 149, 236)
                };

            MainPage = startView;
        }
        #endregion Constructor

        protected override void OnStart ()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep ()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Application developers override this method to perform actions
        /// when the application resumes from a sleeping state.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnResume ()
        {

        }

        #region IBranchSessionInterface implementation

        public void InitSessionComplete(BranchUniversalObject buo, BranchLinkProperties blp)
        {
            if (blp.feature == "feature")
            {
                _navService.NavigateTo<FeatureViewModel>();
            }
        }

        public void SessionRequestError(BranchError error)
        {
            var e = error;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

FirebaseMessagingService.cs

```cs
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Util;
using Firebase.Messaging;
using Xamarin.Essentials;

namespace Crowdkeep.Time.Droid.Services
{
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMessagingService";
        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            Log.Debug(TAG, "From: " + message.From);

            var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);

            InitializeChannels(notificationManager);

            if (IsProductionNotification(message))
            {
                SendProductionNotification(message, notificationManager, this);
            }
            else
            {
                SendTestNotification(message, notificationManager);
            }
        }

        private static bool IsProductionNotification(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            return message.GetNotification() != null;
        }

        private void SendTestNotification(RemoteMessage message, NotificationManager notificationManager)
        {
            var notification = CreateNotification(message.Data["message"], message.Data["branch"], this);
            notificationManager.Notify(0, notification);
        }

        private static void SendProductionNotification(RemoteMessage message, NotificationManager manager, Context context)
        {
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + message.GetNotification().Body);
            var notification = CreateNotification(message.GetNotification().Body, "https://mycompanymyapp.test-app.link/feature", context);
            manager.Notify(0, notification);
        }

        private static void InitializeChannels(NotificationManager manager)
        {
            if (DeviceInfo.Version.Major < 8 || manager.GetNotificationChannel(MainActivity.ChannelId) != null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var channel = new NotificationChannel(MainActivity.ChannelId, "Crowdkeep", NotificationImportance.Default)
            {
                Description = "Default Channel"
            };

            manager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        private static Notification CreateNotification(string messageBody, string link, Context context)
        {
            var pendingIntent = SetupNotificationIntent(link, context);

            var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context, MainActivity.ChannelId)
                .SetContentTitle("Message")
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                .SetContentText(messageBody)
                .SetAutoCancel(true)
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .SetVisibility(NotificationVisibility.Public);

            return notificationBuilder.Build();
        }

        private static PendingIntent SetupNotificationIntent(string link, Context context)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            intent.PutExtra("branch", link);
            intent.PutExtra("branch_force_new_session", true);

            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, MainActivity.NotificationId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
            return pendingIntent;
        }
    }
}
```

Json Sent via Notification:

```cs
{"data":{"message":"Click this notification to go to the best feature of the app!", "branch": "https://mycompanymyapp.test-app.link/feature"}}
```

**EDIT (1/7/2019)**

I'm able to reproduce this in the Test Bed. I forked my own copy of Branch and added a branch called initsessioncomplete-push-notification-issue, [which you can access here](https://github.com/prec/xamarin-branch-deep-linking.git). I followed [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm) to setup Firebase and Azure Notification Hubs. In the solution, the only thing you'll have to modify are the two strings in the AppConstants class in the TestBed.Droid project, and add your google-services.json file to the root of the Droid project (the .csproj is already configured properly to read it).

As far as I can tell, I see a successful call being made to the Branch API when I click the push notification, but InitSessionComplete is never called.

Answer (score 0):

Joon from Branch here. Can you double check that you are using the correct Branch Key in your AndroidManifest? I noticed that you are testing with a test Branch Link so you'll have to use your test Branch Key.

Comment: I have a branch key set in strings.xml with the test key:

<string name="branch_key">key_test_REMOVED</string>

Comment: Joon, please see my edits. I am able to reproduce the issue in the test bed, and if you want you can grab the fork I mentioned in my edit and check out the initsessioncomplete-push-notification-issue branch.